# sort lines in a file by version number

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm using linux and I have a file like this:

```
0.b10_to_1.0.txt, 0 , 56 , 14
0.b3_to_0.b6.txt, 5 , 56 , 7
0.b6_to_0.b7.txt, 1 , 17 , 7
0.b7_to_0.b8.txt, 0 , 34 , 14
0.b8_to_0.b9.txt, 1 , 20 , 5
0.b9_to_0.b10.txt, 2 , 139 , 24
1.0_to_1.1.txt, 0 , 0 , 1
1.1.1_to_1.1.2.txt, 1 , 0 , 0
1.1.2_to_1.1.3.txt, 0 , 0 , 0
1.1_to_1.1.1.txt, 0 , 0 , 0
```

This is actually the result I get from using the command sort but as you can see `0.b10` is the first line while I want it to be the line after the line starting with `0.b9` and `1.1` is the last line while I'd like it to come before `1.1.1`. That is, I want to sort it by version number.

Is there a easy way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what your looking for, but:

```
sed 's/[.b]//g' <yourfile> | sort -n
```

produces:

```
03_to_06txt, 5 , 56 , 7
06_to_07txt, 1 , 17 , 7
07_to_08txt, 0 , 34 , 14
08_to_09txt, 1 , 20 , 5
09_to_010txt, 2 , 139 , 24
010_to_10txt, 0 , 56 , 14
10_to_11txt, 0 , 0 , 1
11_to_111txt, 0 , 0 , 0
111_to_112txt, 1 , 0 , 0
112_to_113txt, 0 , 0 , 0
```

The decimal and 'b' prevent you from sorting numerically.